# How to authenticate windows AD group members to login to Linux systems without joining to windows domain

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, suse, sssd

Please help me to get the steps to do on Centos/SUSE to use windows active directory LDAP feature alone for Linux clients to authenticate users belongs to a AD group instead of joining all Linux machines to windows domain.

Comment: Can you explain what you see as the difference between "authenticating against AD" and "joining the domain"? To me both mean exactly the same as far as Linux clients are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

As a non-windows user, I'm not sure what "instead of joining all Linux machines to the windows domain" means.  However, it's not hard to authenticate with AD on linux clients.

It's a big subject, so I'm not going to write an entire walkthrough here, especially since lots exist already.  However, some keywords to help you find a walkthrough are `sssd` which is an authentication tool which does this and "LDAP client" which is the generic way to say that you can authenticate with an LDAP (AD) server.

Here are some guides I found with a quick search:

- [Administrator's Guide for RHEL 6: Configuring an LDAP Client to use SSSD by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ol_sssd_ldap.html)
- [Configuring authentication and authorization in RHEL by Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_authentication_and_authorization_in_rhel/configuring-sssd-to-use-ldap-and-require-tls-authentication_configuring-authentication-and-authorization-in-rhel)
- [How to configure LDAP client by using SSSD for authentication on CentOS by HP](https://support.datafabric.hpe.com/s/article/How-to-configure-LDAP-client-by-using-SSSD-for-authentication-on-CentOS?language=en_US)